# How can I use a Python cgi script to kill the browser that launched it?

Tags: python, apache, macos, cross-browser

I'm doing this in MacOs 10.4. My web page posts some data to a Python script, and I would like the script to finish off by shutting down the browser. I am trying to do this calling

```
os.system("kill 210")   # where 210, say, is the browser's id number
```

but this doesn't work. In the Apache error log I see the message:

```
kill: (210) - Operation not permitted
```

Presumably the Apache server doesn't have permission to kill a process that I started. Is there a way to give it permission, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: I would be surprised if you can implement this as described above, even if that webbrowser is surfing an address on localhost.  You can get them to close the *page* with javascript, but you can't force  their browser to close that I know of.

Comment: Does apache have the powers to spawn an applescript? I'm sure it would be able to close a browser.  It does seem a quite odd thing to do though.

Comment: @neil: Possibly, but it would be running as the same user as the Apache server, which we've already established does not have sufficient privileges to kill the relevant process.

Comment: @neil @mdm I'd still recommend checking.  AppleScript might be capable of easy privilege escalation, legit or otherwise, given its intended purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you starting your web browser?

You should have a second script that would start the web browser, allow you to paste data -
or automate the whole process, for that you could use "[selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)" if you want and this script would have no issues with closing the browser.

Comment: Yes, that approach worked. The new script opens the browser and then repeatedly sleeps until it spots a file (created by my Python script) that indicates that the web page's work is done. Finally, it can use 'kill' to finish the browser off.